# How to integrate of the derivative of a variable?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

How to calculate integrals of the type

$$
\int \frac{d\phi}{dt}d\phi,
$$

$$
\int \phi \, d\left(\frac{d\phi}{dt}\right)
$$

and

$$
\int \sin\left(\frac{d\theta}{dt}\right)\,d\theta
$$
?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In each case there needs to be a known relationship between the variables in order to perform the integration.

In the first case, if $\phi=\phi(t)$ then $$I_1=\int\left(\frac{d\phi}{dt}\right)^2\,dt$$

likewise in the second case, $$I_2=\int\phi\frac{d^2\phi}{dt^2}\,dt$$

In the third case, provided $\theta=\theta(t),$ $$I_3=\int\sin\left(\frac{d\theta}{dt}\right)\frac{d\theta}{dt}\,dt$$

Comment: Just wondering if you could expand a bit more on this, and if you could explain what kind of rule/substitution you used in your answer.

Comment: Parametric integration in the first case, i.e. $dx=\frac{dx}{dt}dt$, Integration by substitution in the second and third cases.

Comment: Thanks, that makes more sense now.